# es6 accessor for export class function

Tags: ecmascript-6, getter-setter, aurelia

I started working with Aurelia with ES7 and I can't figure out how to make a function public when it needs to have an argument list.

This works:

```
export class dummy{
  get doSomething(){
    return "something";
  }
}

dummy.doSomething()
```

BUT if I modify the function to have an argument list, I get an error:

```
get doSomething(x){
    ...
ERR: A 'get' accessor cannot have parameters.
```

I tried a variety of things that didn't work and Googling it is coming up with nothing. How do I declare a public function in an exported class that accepts an argument and returns a value?

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing specific here about ES7. That's all ES6.

Comment: Remember, dummy is a class, not an instance of an object. Use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of the class. e.g. `var instance = new dummy();` then you can access the property `var foo = instance.doSomething;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get` declares a [**getter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). They are accessed like normal properties (i.e. not methods):

```
var foo = instance.doSomething;
```

That's why getters cannot have parameters.

If you don't want that, but want a method instead, remove it:

```
export class dummy{
  doSomething(x){
    return "something";
  }
}
```

If you merely use the class as a "method bag", i.e. you are not planning to create multiple instances of it, use an object instead:

```
export var dummy = {
  doSomething(x){
    return "something";
  }
};
```

Comment: That gives me 'doSomething is not a function'

Comment: How are you trying to call the method?`dummy.doSomething()` won't work, since the **class** doesn't have such a method. An **instance** of the class has: `var instance = new dummy(); instance.doSomething()`. Or, as I said, use an object instead.

Comment: valicheck's answer above shows how I'm using it via the import {Dummy} statement. Unfortunately, his answer isn't working either. I thought this would be an easy answer. LOL

Comment: Seems to be working now. Not sure what piece I was missing when I first asked this question, but the code sees it now. Thanks.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some examples for dummy in es6:

dummy.js

```
export class Dummy{
  get myGetter() {
    return '456'
  }
}

Dummy.doSomething = (x) => {
    return "something";
}
```

then

```
import {Dummy} from 'dummy'
console.log(Dummy.doSomething(123)); // => "something"
let myDummy = new Dummy();
console.log(myDummy.myGetter); // => "456"
```

Comment: In dummy.js adding the new code at the bottom says "Dummy is not defined". If I move it into the export {} block it says, "this can only be used in ts files". If I put it in the export{} block with this.doSomething... it says "unexpected token"

Comment: do you use Typescript? my example works for plain es6 js with babel